# how to get all users in redis

Tags: node.js, redis

I have the following code .

```
var redis = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient();


user_rahul = { 
     username: 'rahul'

   };
user_namita = {
  username: 'namita'
};
client.hmset('users.rahul', user_rahul);
client.hmset('users.namita', user_namita);
var username = "rahul"; // From a POST perhaps
client.hgetall("users" , function(err, user) {
  console.log(user);
});
```

I want to get all the users list how i can get all users list this what i tried but its not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting the users in their own hash, so when you do hgetall users, you are trying to get all the members of the users hash. You should do:

```
var redis = require("redis"),
client = redis.createClient();
user_rahul = { 
    username: 'rahul'
};
user_namita = {
    username: 'namita'
};
client.hset('users', user_rahul, 'Another Value, Pass Maybe?');
client.hset('users', user_namita, 'Another Value, Pass Maybe?');
var username = "rahul"; // From a POST perhaps
client.hgetall("users" , function(err, user) {
    console.log(user);
});
```

You should consider using a list instead, if you dont need any data in the second hash value

Comment: You should use that function with caution. It is a very nice function, but it also one of the slowest functions in Redis. So, it has the chance to drag your site performance down. If you want to do it like that, then you should use a set.

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
var flow = require('flow'); //for async calls
var redis = require("redis").createClient();

function AddUser(user,callback){
 flow.exec(
   function(){
     //AI for Keep unique
     redis.incr('nextUserId',this);
   },
   function(err,userId){
     if(err) throw err;
     this.userId = userId;
     redis.lpush('users',userId,this.MULTI()); 
     redis.hmset('user:'+userId+':profile',user,MULTI());
   },
   function(results){
      results.forEach(function(result){
    if(result[0]) throw result[0];
      });

     callback(this.userId);
   }
 );
}

user_rahul = {username: 'rahul'};
user_namita = {username: 'namita'};

//Add user
AddUser(user_rahul,function(userId){
    console.log('user Rahul Id' + userId);

});

AddUser(user_namita,function(userId){
    console.log('user Namita Id' + userId);

});


//users

function Users(callback){
var users = [];

 flow.exec(
    function(){
      redis.lrange('users',0,-1,this);
    },
    function(err,userIds){
      if(err) throw err;

     flow.serialForEach(userIds,function(userId){
        redis.hgetall('user:'+userId+':profile',this);
     },
     function(err,val){
       if(err) throw err;
       users.push(val);
     },
     function(){
      callback(users);
     });
    } 
 );
}


//call
Users(function(users){
   console.log(users);
});
```

Comment: looks interesting , what about geting a single particular user ?

Answer (score 0):

For Single User

```
function getUser(userId,callback){
 redis.hgetall('user:'+ userId +':profile',function(err,profile){
        if(err) throw err;
        callback(profile);  
    });
}   

getUser(1,function(profile){
    console.log(profile);
});
```